# What does "get excel up" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english

Does it mean "Open an Excel sheet and work with it"?

"By 2008, Deane, who was at various times an accountant, stay-at-home mom and university employee, had a simple plan to launch a business; it started with tea in the kitchen. "I thought, obviously, what you do is you go home, and if you are British, you have a cup of tea, and you put the computer on in the kitchen and you get excel up," she says."

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/13/this-mom-built-a-65-million-business-the-cambridge-satchel-company.html

Comment: The only contexts in English, where the words "get excel up" occur, involve the software program;  **excel** is otherwise a verb, and it would be ungrammatical to say "get {bare infinitive} up".  You could have reasoned this out by consulting a dictionary and looking at whether the word  **excel** can be a noun.

Comment: If they mean "the computer program Excel" they should have capitalized it, because it's a proper name.  But it might just be an editorial error, since *excel* is also a verb.

Comment: I did use this link http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/excel?q=excel, and this one: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get-up_2?q=get+up, but I didn't see any good explanation for the meaning of "get {bare infinitive} up".

Comment: There is no grammatical construction which follows the pattern `get {bare infinitive} up`, @haile.  The pattern is "get {something} up" and the only "something" called "excel" is a software program called "Excel".

Answer (score 1):

*Get up* is a phrasal verb meaning "to awaken."  It can take an object like *get X up* meaning to awaken X from sleep.

This can be figuratively used to mean "to start" or "to prepare for use."

It usually implies that doing this is a process and takes some time.

We can infer two things from this figurative use of *get up*:

- that Deane's computer may be old and slow and takes a while to start Excel,
- that Deane likely keeps Excel open all day.